# How to redirect from php function to set,cookie, triggered by ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cookies

I'm trying to set a cookie on my web page.
After the cookie's set i would like to redirect him on page instant of doing nothing and wait the user to refresh the page to actualise the cookie.

I am using php jQuery 3.4 to do so.
I tried to refresh the page after the function in JQuery but it don't seems to be triggered.
I tried to use `header('Location: /index.php')` after the cookie set, but it didn't work either. Guess because the cookie set in the HTTP request or from the `header(Content-Type :application/json)`

Here is my javascript function

```js
//get value from a search bar
var option = $(".search-text").val();
        //use ajax to sent it to my php file
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'script_php/cookie.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data:{functionname: 'cookie', arguments: option},

            success: function (obj, textstatus){
                if( !('error' in obj) ) {
                  yourVariable = obj.result;
              }
              else {
                  console.log(obj.error);
              }
            }
        });
```

Here is the php triggered

```php
<?php
        //get the infos from the js file
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $Result = array();

        //stock them inside an array
    $Result['succes'] = cookie($_POST['arguments']);



    function cookie($name){
        setcookie("user", $name, time() + (86400 * 365.25), "/");
                header('Location: /index.php');
    }

    $Result = array();

?>
```

I would like the cookie to be set and then to return the page index.php

The actual output is the cookie being set but the page to stand still

Comment: Presuming that your PHP code is in `cookie.php`, which is called via AJAX, it's not possible for the client to be redirected in this way.  You are calling `cookie.php` and then redirecting _that script_ to `/index.php`.  You need to do the redirection when you receive the result to your AJAX call

Comment: @Martin I tried to use document.redirect('/index.php') after my ajax called (in or outside of the succes function) but it didn't trigger.
PS: you are presuming right my php is cookie.php

Comment: so `success: function() { window.location.href = "/index.php"; }`

Comment: @epascarello i tried already, and i updated my page with it right now, but it still do not work

Comment: What does not work?

Comment: @Herue "What does not work?" is an excellent question.

Is the `jQuery.ajax()` actually running? What is the event that triggers it? Is that event firing? How and when does the event listener get attached? Does the `success`callback actually run? If so, what is the response? If not, what is the error code?

Comment: So, my `Jquery.ajax()` is triggered on a `typicalbutton.onclick()` and is running since you can refresh the main page and see the new cookie.
I am not sure the `success function()` is triggered since i try to `console.log('test')` and nothing was shown.
You can see more on the web site which is free to access on [my web page](https://page-daccueil.000webhostapp.com) if you would like to.

Comment: ```js
$('#agree').on('click', function(){

            var option = $(".search-text").val();
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'script_php/cookie.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                data:{functionname: 'cookie', arguments: option},

                success: function (obj, textstatus){
                    console.log('test');
                }
            });
        });
```
Is my entire js function

Answer (score 0):

I'm having some trouble understanding what you're trying to do, but I think I see multiple problems.

In your PHP snippet, you are overwriting $Result with an empty array. Not sure you want to do that.

You define a function `cookie($name)`, but you don't call the function anywhere, so it's not executed..

Your PHP script, if it is being run at all, is not outputting any data to the client, other than the http header.

As noted in the comment above, if you want the browser to go somewhere else, you can do it client-side and in this case I think you have to. So upon success, i.e., in your callback:

```
document.location = "/index.php"
```

If you're not already using a debugging tool like the Firefox console, you should. Then you can see what's happening in your xhr requests and responses.

Comment: I am trying to set a cookie with the value of my input when i click on a button.
My js run when i click and the button and call the function cookie with the ajax.
When i try to write any `document.location = "/index.php"` or `header('Location: /index.php')` none of them seems to be called. (tried to use document.location after the ajax called but didn't work)

Comment: as far as that goes, you can use just Javascript to manipulate cookies and navigate to another page. you don't need PHP at all to achieve this.

Comment: True, but my goal was to get better on few langage and know how to use them together. This is the reason why i wanted to achieved it